# Reading Custom column name instead of Value from excel using Oledb

Tags: c#, datatable, oledb, oledbdataadapter

[image]

I have Excel Data Like above. Whenever i trying to get the value as  **12/1/2015**. I used to get **1-Dec,2-Dec etc** Like this image

[image: DataSet Visualizer]

```
 bool hasHeaders = true;
        string HDR = hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No";
        string strConn;
        if (path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR =" + HDR + ";IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
        else
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
```

retrieving the data from Excel.

```
  OleDbDataAdapter dataHeader = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT  * FROM [" + sheet + Coords + "]", Connection);
            dataHeader.Fill(tableHeader);
```

please find the mistake.

Comment: did you try `$('#MyTable').bootgrid('reload');`